Astro.js: Create a navigation structure per folder
I have an Astro website like follows:

Different department folders foo, bar, etc.
For each folder, there is a different navigation menu, used by the pages inside.
There are some common shared MDX pages in the parent folder, e.g. about.mdx.

My problem is:
foo/about.astro links to the shared ../about.mdx. The latter is rendered by some ~/layouts/MDXPageLayout.astro component.
The component needs to know if the page comes from foo/about.astro or somewhere else to know what menu to show.
Here is a minimal working example:
The foo/about.astro page:
---
import  MDXPage  from '../about.mdx';
---
<MDXPage folder="foo" />

The common ../about.mdx page:
---
title: About page
layout: ~/layouts/MDXPageLayout.astro
---

We are ACME Industries.

The layout page ~/layouts/MDXPageLayout.astro:
---
---
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <p>I was called from folder: ... </p>
    </header>
    <main>
      <slot />
    </main>
  </body>
</html>

Where I write <p>I was called from folder: ... </p>, I should be able to detect the param folder="foo" in about.astro.
Then, I would be able to build an ad hoc folder based menu.

You could extract this info from Astro.url which will be the url of the current request.

Uh, that was simple: {Astro.url.pathname.split('/')[1]}. Thank you.

You can use Astro.url from any Astro component which will contain the URL of the current request.
.pathname will return the path of the current page and as you already figured out, splitting it on / and extracting the element at index 1 will give the name of the first segment of the path:
console.log(Astro.url.pathname.split('/'))
console.log(Astro.url.pathname.split('/')[1])

In /foo/about this will print:
[ '', 'foo', 'about' ]
foo

